# I use the example named MoviePlayer from SDK 3.0, but it sometimes crashes

Tags: movieplayer

I use the example named MoviePlayer from SDK 3.0, but it sometimes crashes.

PS: I never change any code.

---

Question 1:

My enviroment:

> lan media server:10.0,0.118

I enter an MP4 address:

> http://10.0.0.118/1.mp4

It works fine, but sometimes it crashes.

> using gdb:bt
> mach_msg_trap
>
> mach_msg
> CFRunLoopRunSpecific
> CFRunLoopRunInMode
> GSEventRunModal
> GSEventRun
> UIApplicationMain
> main

What does it mean? I never modify any code.

---

Question 2:

And sometimes, if I play an MP4 file, and then I play it again, the screen of the simulater will shock. If I play another MP4 file it works fine.

How can I make it work?

---

Question 3:

The delegate named `MPMoviePlayerContentPreloadDidFinishNotification` does not work the first time  I play the movie. If I play it again or I play another movie, it is called.

Why?

Comment: Excuse me, but which SDK? Or is there some product "SDK"? I only know it as "Software development kit", which is a rather generic term.

Comment: This sounds like iPhone SDK. Your question is very generic and unclear. If you expect people to help you, you might want to put a bit more effort into phrasing a useful question...

Answer (score 0):

1. Question 2) This shock and blinking is only
   a bug in the emulator. It is not
   happening on a real iPhone device so
   don't worry about it.
2. Question 3) I too saw
   that the delegate named
   `MPMoviePlayerContentPreloadDidFinishNotification`
   does not work the first time 
   I play the movie which is totally
   strange. Maybe this is fixed in
   newest firmware? I don't know. I can't
   check it. Did you find any workaround for Question 3?